# phonegap basics: getting the notifications plugin to work

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have created a really really simple and most basic phonegap app with just 3 very simple files: index.html, config.xml and main.js

In theory the code should simply invoke a native notification to show up a message (just like a javascript alert() call).  I am using phoengap build to build the app and I tested it on an android tablet (asus transformer pad infinity) running android 4.2.1.

After have stripped down the code to the very bare minimum, I still can't get the notification plugin to work.

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Notify</h1>

<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.blink.testapp"
        versionCode = "1"
        version     = "1.0.0">

    <name>My first app</name>

    <description>
        My first app
    </description>

    <author href="http://test.com" email="test@test.com">
        Aa Blink
    </author>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.10" />


</widget>
```

main.js

```
var app = {
    showBrowserAlert: function (message, title) {
        alert(title ? (title + ": " + message) : message);
    },
    showNativeAlert: function (message, title) {
        navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.showBrowserAlert('My first browser alert', 'Info');
        self.showNativeAlert('My first native alert', 'Info');
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

The showBrowserAlert is successfuly invoked.
The showNativeAlert fails.

What is my problem?  This should be so simple.  Many sites and tutorials have this same code.  However I can't get it to work.  Probably it's right in front of my eyes but I cannot see it...

[ZIP can be downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6599473/public_html.zip)

Comment: My first guess would be related to the device ready event.  Plugins are not ready for use until the device ready event has been fired. Try something like:  `document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.initialize, false);`

Comment: Where are you calling the function? You define it but then I can't see where you are invoking it?

Comment: @Ramon, I have s set of [PUBLIC DEMO Apps](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html). The one you want is [Phonegap-Notification-Test](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Notification-Test). You are welcome to copy as much as you need.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect in main.js -> showNativeAlert

Comment: @laughingpine - you were right.  The deviceready was the issue...